# Inserting difference of columns between every column successively

Tags: python, pandas

I have the result of a count on a dataframe that is a single row long, like so:

```
Users Address Email Phone Work
552    343     207   117   57
```

I want to insert, between each column, the difference between the second column and the previous, so that I get:

```
Users DiffAdd Address DiffEmail  Email DiffPhone Phone  DiffWork Work
 552    -209   343      -136      207     -90     117      -60    57
```

Alternatively, if it's possible I'd simply replace the values of each column with its corresponding difference, with the result:

```
 Users Address Email  Phone Work 
 552    -209   -136    -90  -60
```

I tried to do the latter case so that I'd replace the value with the difference, but this then applied the new value immediately to the next calculation, so I got wild values that did not make sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

- get difference of all columns by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), change columns names by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by columns `axis=1`
- reorder columns names by flattening zipped both columns names with subset `[]`
- remove first column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

---

```
df1 = df.diff(axis=1).add_prefix('Diff')
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)

c = list(sum(zip(df1.columns, df.columns), ()))
print (c)
['DiffUsers', 'Users', 'DiffAddress', 'Address', 'DiffEmail',
 'Email', 'DiffPhone', 'Phone', 'DiffWork', 'Work']

df = df[c].iloc[:, 1:]
print (df)

   Users  DiffAddress  Address  DiffEmail  Email  DiffPhone  Phone  DiffWork  \
0    552       -209.0      343     -136.0    207      -90.0    117     -60.0   

   Work  
0    57
```

Alternatively:

```
df2 = df.diff(axis=1).fillna({'Users':df['Users']})
print (df2)
   Users  Address  Email  Phone  Work
0  552.0   -209.0 -136.0  -90.0 -60.0
```